# Erlang: configuring cover via rebar

Tags: erlang, rebar

My project is using a websocket server. Only for testing purposes, I also have an erlang websocket client implementation which resides in the `test/` folder along with the tests.

Now, when I run the tests via `rebar` with `{cover_enabled, true}` in my `rebar.config`, I also get coverage reported for the modules of the websocket client. I don't want this in my reports.

Cover documentation says I should create a cover specification file containing `{excl_mods, [websocket_client]}.`

But how do I convince rebar to use this file?

Cover documentation:

- http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/cover_chapter.html
- http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/cover.html

rebar:

- https://github.com/basho/rebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I asked rebar author @dizzyd.

It turns out that this cover option is not supported by eunit, which I use to execute my tests.